# Firebase authentication is working but firestore is denying request as Missing or Insufficient permissions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an android app running for the last few months. I upgraded to the Blaze plan yesterday and since then Firestore started denying requests with the following error (not sure if these two are related and I am well below my quota)

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Following is my security rule

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Firebase authentication is working fine as I am using

```
fbUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

and I am getting fbUser. but any request to Firestore from my android app is getting denied. Following is the stack trace

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:117)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.EventManager.onError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:166)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.removeAndCleanupTarget(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:534)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.handleRejectedListen(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:418)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.handleRejectedListen(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:317)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.processTargetError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:557)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.handleWatchChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:441)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:53)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.RemoteStore$1.onWatchChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:176)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:108)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.WatchStream.onNext(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:38)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.lambda$onNext$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:119)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$CloseGuardedRunner.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:67)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.AbstractStream$StreamObserver.onNext(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:110)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$1.onMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:124)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:563)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:229)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at io.grpc.Status.asException(Status.java:541)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Util.exceptionFromStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:115)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: even if I use "allow read, write: if true", the requests are getting denied.

Answer (score 0):

Billing plan and security rules are not related.

Your rules reject any request that happens without a user sign-in.  That's the only thing that needs to be satisfied in order to get your query to work.  There's not enough information here to know why a user isn't signed in (if that's what you expect), but that's the only reason for "permission denied" in this, according to what you've shown here.  You'll have to do some debugging to figure that out.

Comment: user is firebase authenticated, as I am using "fbUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();", and I am getting fbUser. The problem happens when I am trying to access firestore.

Comment: Lack of auth is the only explanation given what you've shown here.  Firestore doesn't issue "permission denied" for any reason other than rejection from security rules.  And if your rules require auth, that means there is no auth'd user at the time of the query.

Comment: How to check that if that's the issue as even if I use  "allow read, write: if true", the requests are getting denied. How to debug this issue? Pardon my knowledge as I am new to android and firestore and this is my first app

Comment: Then you are modifying the wrong rules for the app. You could be in the wrong project.  This is not something that Stack Overflow can debug for you.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, but I'm modifying the right security rules in the right project. And this isn't something I am asking StackOverflow to debug but some way to debug the issue.

Comment: If you set set security rules to allow full access, and you still get permission denied, then you are not working with the correct rules.

Comment: I checked in 100 times now, I'm writing rules for the app in question here and it's still not working. I created a new android app and linked it to the same firebase, that app too doesn't work

Comment: Hey @SandeepChoudhary, I am getting the same issue. For me, it's throwing in the production build and it's working fine in the debug build. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No @Shubh, I actually created another project and exported whole data to new project.

Comment: @SandeepChoudhary, I will update here if I find any solution. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a whole solution, but a step in a direction.

I was having the exact same problem with example application GuestBook [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/guestbook-cloud-firestore).

**One fix was that I created from scratch a new firebase project**... It worked... (the source code is the same, other than the project-Id in one file).
same security rules as the old non-working project .. which to me says that the original problem does not lie in the security rules.

So the question is what is the difference in configurations?
The only difference that I can imagine is the configuration of the service accounts  ... do 'Roles' play a part? if so, in what way?

One thing I did notice was the in the firebase console, the service account was based on 'firebase-adminsdk-rk0ap'..  as opposed to the 'firebase-service-account' service account.  With the old project, neither worked.
For the new project I used 'firebase-adminsdk-xxxx' account

What also didn't work was reinitializing at the console (the steps in the GuestBook example):

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud init (reinitialized current project)
gcloud app create  (wasn't necessary, because already activated).
```

One error (don't know if related) upon the first call to the browser was:

```
WARNING: Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 94:a0:2d:dd:19:25:bf:f2
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Then when the application tries to access/write datastore:

```
"POST /sign HTTP/1.1" 302
"GET /index.jsp?guestbookName=default HTTP/1.1" 200
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

(I would have put this in a comment, but I don't have permission).